# FTP List not working on Server 2016 Datacenter

Tags: azure, ftp, windows-server-2016

I'm having a strange issue with FTP on an Azure 2016 Datacenter server.

I'm able to FTP to an external site but am unable to retrieve the directory listing or file list.

I've tried using the vendors external app and also in FileZilla. FileZilla will connect, but as you as you try changing any directory it errors out.

Does FTP need to be enabled in GroupPolicy or anything on Server 2016?  My firewall ports are open, even tested with all ports allowed.

Comment: there is a document how to set up windows firewall with filezilla - everything followed? https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration

Comment: FTP is an odd protocol in the regard that **two connections** are used. The first is the control connection, by default an FTP server will listen on TCP port 21 for that. The control connection is used for authentication and issuing commands. The actual file transfers and things such as the output of a directory listing go over a second TCP connection, the DATA connection. Your symptoms indicate that the data connection fails. - For further troubleshooting you need to check if your server is using passive or active FTP and what happens when you try to switch between those in your client

Comment: Some details would go a long way to our being able to provide insightful answers. `I'm able to FTP to an external site but am unable to retrieve the directory listing or file list.` - What happens when you try? What messages, if any, do you get? `FileZilla will connect, but as you as you try changing any directory it errors out.` - What is the error message? `My firewall ports are open, even tested with all ports allowed.` - What ports, specifically?